# Using addControls to call different csv files in rCharts

Tags: r, csv, rcharts

I am trying to use different `csv` files for plotting similar plots by using `rCharts`. Here's my attempt (with a simpler dataset):

```
data1 <- structure(list(Type = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C","C","C","C"),
                    S= c(0.03, 0.04, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.10, 0.01, 0.06, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.1, 0.05, 0.07,0.17), 
                    C= c(0.43, 0.24, 0.13, 0.24, 0.15, 0.11, 0.33, 0.13, 0.23, 0.44, 0.55, 0.17, 0.75, 0.07,0.87), 
                    L = c(1.43, 1.24, 0.93, 2.24, 1.15, 1.21, 2.43, 1.13, 0.93, 0.94, 2.45, 1.17, 1.45, 1.70, 2.32)),
               .Names = c("Type", "S", "C", "L"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
data2 <- data1[2:4]
library(rCharts)
r1 <- rPlot(C ~ S, data = data1, type = 'point', size = 'L')
r1$addControls('x', 'S', names(data2))
r1
```

The output is like this:

[image]

I want to create the plots for different Type `("A", "B","C")`. But I am not able to add the group category in `addControls`. My original dataset are in different csv files. I have created a simpler example for easier understanding. Is there anyway to call different `csv` files in `rCharts` like `Shiny`?

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
your_data <- read.csv("yourFilesName.csv")
```

Also see
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html
for a guide of importing data, including csv, with R (including rCharts, Shiny).